# Should I use weak self in variable?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have case where my property getter is referencing to the `self` and in the way I have suspicion that it will hold `self` and will never release it.Could you please explain if I am not making mistake in this case?

```
 private var storyboard: UIStoryboard {
    get {
      return UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of:self)))
    }
 }
```

Comment: A property getter isn't a closure, the compiler won't even let you use unowned self.

Comment: A computed property is no more than a glorified (pair of) method(s) – there's no retain cycle concerns. Did you test it (i.e put a `print` in `deinit`)?

Comment: @Hamish yes and I have memory leaks that are connected with class that contains this property.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Your problem is likely elsewhere then – I don't see anything wrong with the code you've shown us. It would be great if you could reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: @Hamish thx I find issue that is connected with CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont. You were right. Could you please answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not making a mistake – a computed property is no more than  a glorified method / pair of methods. On its own, there are no retain cycle concerns.

`self` is simply an implicit parameter passed upon calling the getter or setter of the computed property, and will be the instance that the property is being accessed on – it's not stored or captured by the property itself.